# How to Comparison Validate in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "MIN_SALARY")

private Integer minSalary;

@Basic
@Column(name = "MAX_SALARY")

  private Integer maxSalary;
```

How can I create a validation where minimum salary cannot be greater than maximum salary in hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a [check](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-check-constraint/) constraint in your SQL database just to be 100% sure.
2. Create an interface that will describe the contract for the salary range.

```java
public interface SalaryRange {
    Integer getMinSalary();
    Integer getMaxSalary();
}
```

3. Create the annotation for validation

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Constraint(validatedBy = SalaryRangeValidator.class)
public @interface ValidateSalaryRange {
}
```

4. Make your entity implement `SalaryRange` interface and hook your fields to the interface getters.
5. Create a validator for range validation logic.

```java
public class SalaryRangeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateSalaryRange, SalaryRange> {

    @Override public void initialize(ValidateSalaryRange date) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(SalaryRange range, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        return range.getMinSalary() < range.getMaxSalary();
    }
}
```

6. Annotate your entity with `@ValidateSalaryRange`

More info about Hibernate validator [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-constraintannotation)